# Intellij Idea: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfil

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a very simple project:

```
 public class untitled3 {
        public static void main(){
            System.out.println("ciao mondo");
        }
    }
```

Then I have created the jar: `Project Structure -> Artifacts -> JAR -> From Module to dependencies -> OK -> OK -> Build Artifacts`

I got this error:

> java -jar untitled3.jar
> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile untitled3.jar

when I executed it. Why?

Comment: I think the signature of your main function is invalid. At least until java 8 it needs the parameter `String args[]`.

Comment: @Reporter I have tried that signature too, but I get the same error

Comment: Can you try `String[] args`? Sometimes I mixed it up :(

Comment: Ok solved, I have to select the main class after "From Module to dependencies" :)